# Delphi, my sniffer wont work on WLAN

Tags: delphi, sockets, network-programming, winsock, packet-sniffers

I have a working sniffer program, written in Delphi. Its good in LAN. But when my computer is on WLAN, it wont log anything. Initializing:

```
 if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), Wsa) <> 0) then ErrorMsg ('WSAStartup');

 //Create a RAW Socket
 sniffer:= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP);
 if (sniffer = INVALID_SOCKET) then ErrorMsg ('Socket');

 //Retrive the local hostname
 getmem (hostname, 100);
 if (gethostname(hostname, 100) = SOCKET_ERROR) then ErrorMsg ('Gethostname');

 //Retrive the available IPs of the local host
 local:= gethostbyname(hostname);
 if (local = nil) then ErrorMsg ('Gethostbyname');
 i:= 0;
 repeat
  i:= i + 1;
  Move (local^.h_addr^[i-1], Addr, sizeof(Tinaddr));
 until (local^.h_addr^[i-1] <> #0);

 Players.MyIP:= inet_ntoa(Addr);
 if Players.MyIP = '0.0.0.0' then
        begin
         Showmessage ('No IP!?'); halt;
        end;
 _in:= 0;
 FillChar (Dest, SizeOf(Dest), 0);
 Move (local^.h_addr^[_in], dest.sin_addr.s_addr, sizeof(dest.sin_addr.s_addr));
 dest.sin_family:= AF_INET;
 dest.sin_port  := 0;

 if (bind(sniffer, @dest, sizeof(dest))) = SOCKET_ERROR then ErrorMsg ('Bind');

 j:= 1;
 if (WSAIoctl(sniffer, SIO_RCVALL, @j,4, nil, 0, LPDWORD(@_in),nil, nil)) = SOCKET_ERROR then ErrorMsg ('WSAIoctl');
```

capturing thread

```
 while not Terminated do
 begin
  mangobyte:= recvfrom (sniffer,Buffer^,65536,0,nil,nil); //Eat as much as u can
  if (mangobyte > 0) then
  begin
   adsasdasd
  end
```

so it wont log anything. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose by WLAN you mean WiFi. Ethernet (LAN) packets are in 802.3 format, WiFi packets are in 802.11 format. I'm not sure what exactly your sniffer is doing, but the parsing of 802.3 frames is different from parsing 802.11 frames. Windows XP and earlier versions didn't support native WiFi, thus the driver had to wrap wireless packets with 802.3 header to emulate ethernet (LAN) packets. Starting from Vista, no wrapping is needed and the OS processes the 802.11 frames directly. Unless you work with WinXP or earlier, you need different parsing for wireless frames.

Answer (score 2):

You are binding to the first available local IP (BTW, don't use `gethostbyname()` to enumerate local IPs, as it is not guaranteed to return the proper values. Use [GetAdaptersInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917.aspx) or [GetAdaptersAddresses()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915.aspx) instead).  If the machine has multiple IPs installed, you may be binding to the wrong IP.  In that situation, you should let the user choose which IP to bind to.